# How to POST PHP to remote ASMX server

Tags: php

I need to make a simple "Hello World" script in PHP that I then need to post to a remote ASMX server. I've already established a connection between PHP and the server by pulling all the arrays from the ASMX server in PHP using cmd.

How wohuld I send my script to the ASMX server so that it can be executed there?

Answer (score 0):

You can send it using FTP or SCP (Secure Copy). FTP and SCP is available on linux and FTP comes default with windows.